# Error in Spring Security 3.2 Configuration File

Tags: xml, spring, spring-security

I am using spring security 3.2. My project is working just fine. But my security configuration file shows two errors

1) at `<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">`

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd',
>   because 1) could not find the      document; 2) the document could not
>   be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .
>     - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'security:http'.

2) at `<security:authentication-manager>`

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'security:authentication-manager'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/*"
        access="hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1') 
        and (isAnonymous() ? false : principal.lastname== 'Scarioni') and over18" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/movies/**/*"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/movies/*"
        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_VIP')" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_switch_user"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_exit_user"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/custom_login"
        requires-channel="https" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check"
        requires-channel="https" />

    <security:remember-me key="terror-key" />

    <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
        success-handler-ref="logoutRedirectToAny" />

    <security:custom-filter ref="switchUser"
        before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/custom_login"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="serverErrorHandler"
        username-parameter="user_param" password-parameter="pass_param" />

    <security:session-management>
        <security:concurrency-control
            max-sessions="1" />
    </security:session-management>

</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="inMemoryUserServiceWithCustomUser" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="switchUser"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="inMemoryUserServiceWithCustomUser" />
    <property name="targetUrl" value="/" />

</bean>

<bean id="expressionHandler"
    class="com.apress.pss.terrormovies.security.CustomWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />

<bean id="inMemoryUserServiceWithCustomUser"
    class="com.apress.pss.terrormovies.spring.CustomInMemoryUserDetailsManager">

    <constructor-arg>

        <list>

            <bean class="com.apress.pss.terrormovies.model.User">

                <constructor-arg value="admin" />
                <constructor-arg value="admin" />

                <constructor-arg>

                    <list>

                        <bean
                            class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority">
                            <constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                        </bean>

                    </list>

                </constructor-arg>

                <constructor-arg value="Scarioni" />
                <constructor-arg value="19" />

            </bean>

            <bean class="com.apress.pss.terrormovies.model.User">

                <constructor-arg value="paco" />
                <constructor-arg value="tous" />

                <constructor-arg>

                    <list>

                        <bean
                            class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority">
                            <constructor-arg value="ROLE_USER" />
                        </bean>

                    </list>

                </constructor-arg>

                <constructor-arg value="Miranda" />
                <constructor-arg value="20" />

            </bean>

            <bean class="com.apress.pss.terrormovies.model.User">

                <constructor-arg value="lucas" />
                <constructor-arg value="fernandez" />

                <constructor-arg>

                    <list>

                        <bean
                            class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority">
                            <constructor-arg value="ROLE_VIP" />
                        </bean>
                        <bean
                            class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority">
                            <constructor-arg value="ROLE_USER" />
                        </bean>

                    </list>

                </constructor-arg>

                <constructor-arg value="Silva" />
                <constructor-arg value="20" />

            </bean>

        </list>

    </constructor-arg>

</bean>

<bean id="logoutRedirectToAny"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
    <property name="targetUrlParameter" value="redirectTo" />
</bean>

<bean id="serverErrorHandler"
    class="com.apress.pss.terrormovies.security.ServerErrorFailureHandler" />
</beans>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Are you actually using Spring Security 3.2 (or up)? Make sure the correct jars are used and it is advised to use the version less schemas instead of the one with versions.

Comment: Sir, I'm using Spring Security 3.2 and the project is working just good. It's the errors I'm concerned about

Comment: By any chance are you using Eclipse, that sometimes has hickups regarding XML validation.

Comment: Yes Sir, I'm using eclipse. What other IDE should I use instead

Comment: Which version of spring (not spring-security) are you using?

Comment: Sir, I'm using Spring 3.2.7